# Erro phpMailer: Network is unreachable (101)

Tags: phpmailer

Estávamos usando o phpMailer para envio de e-mails, mas simplesmente de uma hora para outro o mesmo está com um comportamento estranho não enviando os e-mails.

O erro que ocorre:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101)
```

A configuração é essa:

```
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = '*****';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "contato@cocari.com.br";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "*****";
```

Todas as configurações foram revisadas e todas elas estão corretas.

Comment: Qual servidor e porta esta usando?

Comment: O `cocari.com.br` suporta tls ou ssl?

Comment: Olá @GuilhermeNascimento, sim, suporta.
TLS porta 587

Comment: O erro `Network is unreachable` que dizer que a rede esta inacessível, o host que usou e `cocari.com.br` ou `smtp.cocari.com.br` ou `mail.cocari.com.br`?

Comment: Tente o comando no CMD do Windows algo semelhante a isto `telnet smtp.cocari.com.br 587`, troque o smtp.cocari.com.br pelo seu host de smtp e me diga o resultado. Qual hospedagem esta usando?

Comment: O host usado: mail.cocari.com.br estamos usando nossa própria hospedagem.

Comment: Por telnet está conectando certo.

Comment: Seu servidor e WindowsServer?

Comment: Comunique ao administrador da rede um possivel bloqueio de firewall na porta 587, acredito talvez ser este o problema.